# The printwindow function works on some computers but not on others

Tags: c#, winapi, panel, gdi, user32

I wrote some code inside a Winform.
I have one panel and one PictureBox. As can be seen in the codes below; I open an exe program called Stellerium in the panel. I painted this program, which I opened in the Panel, into the PictureBox with the print window command.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        //private static extern long SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        //[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        //private static extern long SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, long hWndInsertAfter, long x, long y, long cx, long cy, long wFlags);

        //[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        //private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);

        //IntPtr appWin1;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

        public enum PrintWindowOptions : uint
        {
            PW_DEFAULT = 0,
            PW_CLIENTONLY = 1,
            PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT = 2  // Undocumented. Use, e.g., with a WebBrowser
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern internal bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hDC, PrintWindowOptions nFlags);

        public enum DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE : uint
        {
            DWMWA_NCRENDERING_ENABLED = 1,      // [get] Is non-client rendering enabled/disabled
            DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY,           // [set] DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY - Non-client rendering policy - Enable or disable non-client rendering
            DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED,    // [set] Potentially enable/forcibly disable transitions
            DWMWA_ALLOW_NCPAINT,                // [set] Allow contents rendered In the non-client area To be visible On the DWM-drawn frame.
            DWMWA_CAPTION_BUTTON_BOUNDS,        // [get] Bounds Of the caption button area In window-relative space.
            DWMWA_NONCLIENT_RTL_LAYOUT,         // [set] Is non-client content RTL mirrored
            DWMWA_FORCE_ICONIC_REPRESENTATION,  // [set] Force this window To display iconic thumbnails.
            DWMWA_FLIP3D_POLICY,                // [set] Designates how Flip3D will treat the window.
            DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS,        // [get] Gets the extended frame bounds rectangle In screen space
            DWMWA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP,            // [set] Indicates an available bitmap When there Is no better thumbnail representation.
            DWMWA_DISALLOW_PEEK,                // [set] Don't invoke Peek on the window.
            DWMWA_EXCLUDED_FROM_PEEK,           // [set] LivePreview exclusion information
            DWMWA_CLOAK,                        // [set] Cloak Or uncloak the window
            DWMWA_CLOAKED,                      // [get] Gets the cloaked state Of the window. Returns a DWMCLOACKEDREASON object
            DWMWA_FREEZE_REPRESENTATION,        // [set] BOOL, Force this window To freeze the thumbnail without live update
            PlaceHolder1,
            PlaceHolder2,
            PlaceHolder3,
            DWMWA_ACCENTPOLICY = 19
        }

        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern internal int DwmGetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE dwAttribute, out Rectangle pvAttribute, int cbAttribute);
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"notepad.exe") { WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized };
            //using (var p = Process.Start(psi))
            //{
            //    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);
            //    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad.exe"))
            //    {

            //    }

            //    p.WaitForInputIdle();
            //    var handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
            //    if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            //    {
            //        SetParent(handle, panel1.Handle);
            //        MoveWindow(handle, 0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height, true);
            //    }
            //}
        }
        public static Bitmap RenderWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool clientAreaOnly, bool tryGetFullContent = false)
        {
            var printOption = clientAreaOnly ? PrintWindowOptions.PW_CLIENTONLY : PrintWindowOptions.PW_DEFAULT;
            printOption = tryGetFullContent ? PrintWindowOptions.PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT : printOption;
            var hResult = DwmGetWindowAttribute(hWnd, DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE.DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, out Rectangle dwmRect, Marshal.SizeOf<Rectangle>());
            if (hResult < 0)
            {
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hResult);
                return null;
            }

            if (dwmRect.Width <= 0 || dwmRect.Height <= 0) return null;

            var bmp = new Bitmap(dwmRect.Width, dwmRect.Height);
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                var hDC = g.GetHdc();
                try
                {
                    var success = PrintWindow(hWnd, hDC, printOption);
                    if (!success)
                    {
                        // Failed, see what happened
                        var win32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        return null;
                    }
                    return bmp;
                }
                finally
                {
                    g.ReleaseHdc(hDC);
                }
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var image = RenderWindow(this.Handle, true, false))
            {
                if (image is null) return;
                if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) return;
                var panelRect = RectangleToClient(panel1.RectangleToScreen(panel1.ClientRectangle));
                pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
                pictureBox1.Image = image.Clone(panelRect, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (Screen.AllScreens.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Second screen not available !");
            }

            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Stellarium\stellarium.exe") { WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized };
            using (var p = Process.Start(psi))
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
                foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("stellarium"))
                {

                }

                p.WaitForInputIdle();
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
                var handle = p.MainWindowHandle;

                if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    SetParent(handle, panel1.Handle);
                    MoveWindow(handle, 0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can run the software I made on my computer with window10 as seen in the picture below.
[image]

but on my computer with Windows 11, it cannot paint the image inside the panel to the PictureBox with printwindow, as seen below.

[image]

What could be the reason why it works on one computer and not on the other?

I need your support thanks.

Comment: What value did `PrintWindow` return? It's hard to say computers, systems or `stellarium.exe` makes the difference. It looks like [SetWindowDisplayAffinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: It may be the Windows Update issue. See the similar thread https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1319321/kb5027223-and-kb5027231-cause-the-magnification-ap which involves KB5027223 and KB5027231 update.